# Retrieve the same values ​whose data is there or exists and not the rest.In django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

---

I want to have a data that does not have any empty value in database or in row.
I wrote like this in my code.

```
faq = FAQ.objects.values('question','answer','field_id')
```

this the output in my terminal

```
{'question': None, 'answer': None, 'field_id': None}
{'question': 'Test question', 'answer': '<p>Testsaddsf description</p>\r\n', 'field_id': 'TestTest'}
```

i don't want `None` value data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with the [**`__isnull`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#isnull):

```
faq = FAQ.objects.filter(
    question__isnull=False,
    answer__isnull=False,
    field_id__isnull=False
).values('question','answer','field_id')
```

This will thus only include records where none of `question`, `answer` or `field_id` are `NULL`/`None`.