# Django looks in `templates` when loading static file

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I have the following issue:  when I try lo link my `layout.html` to `styles.css` Django looks in the wrong place.
The `layout.html` code which reads:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
```

and the structure of my `encyclopedia` dir is as follows:

```
├── db.sqlite3
├── encyclopedia
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ...
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── encyclopedia
│   │       └── styles.css
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── encyclopedia
│   │  ...     └── search.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── util.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
└── wiki
```

I did check the `settings.py` file in dir `wiki` and it does have a: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` line.
Yet Django keeps looking in `templates` as per the following error message:
[image: error message from VS Code]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Share your view and settings. It looks like it is simply *not* rendering that part at all, and thus has as URL `{% static ... %}`, so not the "translated" URL.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem i want help at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547680/retrieve-the-same-values-whose-data-is-there-or-exists-and-not-the-rest-in-djan

Comment: `{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css'}` is missing a `%` right before the closing `}`.

Comment: Sorry, the code was correct - I just pasted it wrong. It's now edited in my post.

Comment: @WIllem you want me to post the whole `views.py` and `settings.py`? I don't quite understand what you mean by "not rendering that part at all".

Comment: @BernardinoSassolide'Bianchi: you made a typo, you forgot the second `%` in `{% ... %}`, so that means that Django's render engine does not recognize this as a tag, and thus will not "transform" it into a sensical URL...

Comment: Thx but no, that's not the issue. See above.

Comment: Need to see your views.py ... it seems you serve that page in a way so that django does not do any rendering (meaning e.g. tags {% %} are not rendered) but just serves it as html.

Comment: How do you serve the app? Runserver, Apache ...?

Comment: https://github.com/bsassoli/web50/tree/project1

Comment: I use runserver

Comment: 1) You have 2x a "urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()" one in wiki/urls.py and one in encylo../urls.py ... I am not sure if this should only be in wiki/urls.py

Comment: 2) a far as I know you need to define STATIC_DIRS if you want to use staticfiles_urlpatterns()

Comment: HI @Razenstein - I added this in a second time to try to sort this - they were not there originally. Does not seem to make any difference but thx.

Answer (score 1):

There was a type in your code in the href (% right missing)

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
```

Comment: Sorry, the code was correct - I just pasted it wrong. It's now edited in my post.

Comment: Can you post your static part in your setting files? Are other calls to static working properly?

Comment: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` quite simply. The `settings.py` is located in `wiki` dir.